# Programmatially specifying a class to load in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, class, load

Sorry of this appears a bit simple a question, but is there a way to load objects from the db with Hibernate by specifying the class as a variable of the query?

I.e.:

I have

ClazzA, ClazzB, ClazzC

All three classes are mapped to tables ClazzA, ClazzB and ClazzC in the db

I would like to have a variable like so:

Class clazz=obj.getClass();

and then be able to populate a query by specifying the class as part of the query construction:

List objs=session.createQuery(...) ... .list();

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elegant way to do it with HQL queries, but you can use Criteria API:

```
List objs = session.createCriteria(clazz).list();
```

**See also:**

- [Chapter 17. Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql = "select o from " + clazz.getName() + " o where ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String getQuery(Class class) {
   StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder("from ");
   hql.append(class.getCanonicalName());
   ...
   //Here you complete the query.
   ...
   return hql.toString();
}
```